# How do i remove labels from MS Charts Pie chart?

Tags: c#, winforms

the following image shows labels on a pie chart

[Image of my PIE chart](http://i1267.photobucket.com/albums/jj546/snifusbits/pie_zpsafc1e02e.png)

As you can see the legend labels are on the pie chart and chart is not clear.

1. How do I remove those label from the pie chart surface but not from the chart screen?
2. How do I make the pies chart bigger in this case bigger diameter?
3. As I change the size of pie chart, is it possible to change the size of all the other charts?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand your fist question, do you mean you want to remove label form chart surface **but still display the legend**? If that so you could set `Points.Label` to be empty string and set `Points.LegendText` to be the label text.

Such the sample code below (You could adapt it to be fit your code, if it needed.):

```
chart1.Series[0].Points[0].Label = "";
chart1.Series[0].Points[0].LegendText = "2012";

chart1.Series[0].Points[1].Label = "";
chart1.Series[0].Points[1].LegendText = "2013";
```

Where my chart1 has only one series (Series[0]) with two piece of pie (Points[0] and Points[1])

The size of pie will be changed following the size of Chart, so if you want it to be bigger, then you have to set the size of chart.

```
Size size = new System.Drawing.Size(800, 600);
chart1.Size = size;
```

This will be the same for other chart types.

Answer (score 3):

Youc can do like this

```
ChartPie.Series[i]["PieLabelStyle"] = "Disabled";
```

Comment: my app is a windows app, are you saying I could use CSS on winapps? : )

Comment: asp. net chart in your tag

Comment: sorry about that : ( let remove that asp .net tag